# SurefireSensor error sonarQube for gradle android

Tags: android, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube-scan

I am trying latest version of sonar for gradle.Below is code snippet I have written

```
app\build.gradle
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
            property "sonar.jdbc.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance"
            property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName","com.mysql.jdbc.driver"
            property "sonar.projectKey", "com.xyz"
            property "sonar.projectName", "xyz"
            property "sonar.version", "1.0"
            property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
            property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"
            property "sonar.sources", "./src/main/java"
            property "sonar.tests", "./src/test/java"
            property "sonar.java.binaries", "./build/intermediates/classes/debug"
            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "./build/test-results/debug"
            property "sonar.verbose", "false"
            property "sonar.language", "java"
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
        }
}
```

main project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2'
    }
}
```

But running sonarQube , giving below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
> Can not invoke method public java.lang.Class org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.dependsUponCoverageSensors()
```

Please help,how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube server?
What is your version of the SonarQube Java Plugin on the server?

Comment: sonarqube version is 5.5, "sonar-java-plugin-3.9.jar" and sonar-surefire-plugin-3.3.2.jar

Comment: You should remove sonar-surefire-plugin-3.3.2.jar. It is now merged with sonar-java-plugin-3.9.jar

Comment: Check out https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/ for detailed explanation on integrating sonarqube in android